# Can't understand how JToolBarHelper works

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

i'm learning how to develop a Joomla component but i have a problem with my a module.

I've added a toolbar in the admin view of a single item (i have a database of items).

Now i have searched for 'how to save form data in joomla' but i'm confused due the different versions of the cms.

In any case, my question is:

How the cancel button is rendered? I understood that is something related to this line of code

```
    JToolBarHelper::cancel('itemView.cancel');
```

but i can't figure out:

- itemView.cancel is a task, but how this task is processed (i mean in general). How JToolBarHelper works? The doc is really approssimative.
- the generated button don't works. After i click it, i'm taken to a 500 error page. The error code is:

  ```
  View not found [name, type, prefix]: itemviews, html, pesceinreteView
  ```

Thanks guys.

PS: My Joomla version is Joomla! 3.4.8 Stable

Comment: It actually is telling you that it cannot find `pesceinreteViewitemviews`  where it expects to find it.   Check your class name.  Make sure everything matches, Joomla is heavily convention driven.

Comment: Thanks  Elin, it was the class name